# How to run a covariance in for loop in r

Tags: r

I am trying to run a covariance using a for loop but I get an error saying

> "is.numeric(x) || is.logical(x) is not TRUE"

I have created two variables to include the data frames.

```
Var1<-paste("DF",I,"$Column1",sep="")

Var2<-paste("DF",I,"$Column2",sep="")

Cov<-cov(Var1,Var2)
```

If I hardcode the df and columns the code works correctly, but when trying to make it iterative, it doesn't

The variables are loading correctly but not sure what else I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are trying to use column names as variable in a function. When you are using `paste`, you are actually not referencing to column name but to a string of column name i.e. `"df$column1"` is not the same as `df$column1`.

To use the column name as variable in function you can use other method to reference column name i.e.

```r
f = function(column_name){
  mean(mtcars[[column_name]], na.rm = TRUE)
}

f("mpg")
#> [1] 20.09062
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you really wish to use `column_name` as a variable with `$`, then following is the way:

```r
f = function(column_name){
  eval(
    substitute(
      mean(mtcars$column_name), 
      list(column_name=as.name(column_name))
    )
  )
}

f("mpg")
#> [1] 20.09062
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I will try to explain above method briefly, there are three functions to note: `eval`, `substitute` and `as.name`. `as.name` converts the string to a name (or like an object `mtcars`), so your column name changes from `"mpg"` to `mpg`, but `mpg` (as an object) does not exist without the dataframe `mtcars`. So if you were to just refer it like `sum(mpg)` it will throw an error. `substitute`' returns an unevaluated expression, which is evaluated using `eval`. To be honest, this is an advanced stuff, with which I have also struggled to wrap my head around, you can read more about it here: [metaprogramming](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html). My advice would be to use `[[` to refer column name as variable.